# How to show sum of transaction amounts and count in a header tag in an output xml generated in Spring batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I need to create a xml file from some tables (some transactions) using Spring Batch. I need to add a header to the xml containing the sum of total transaction amount and a few details which needs some data that is calculated during processing in batch. I know header could be added using StaxWriterCallback but how to I get the values like sum or total count or any other details which is calculated during the entire processing of the batch. How should I go about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to count or sum (or any other things you need) into `ItemWriter#write()` (as described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html#writingASummaryFooter)).
Follow linked example and use a `StaxWriterCallback` instead of a `FlatFileFooterCallback`

Comment: That node would be added at the end of the xml not at the start of it. I need to have it at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing in chunk ? If no, then you can read all items in writer.